# How can I stop generating md5, sha1 jars being created in maven

Tags: maven, maven-3, md5, sha1

In my maven build although I did pass **-Dchecksum=false**, but still it always generate multiple jars with extension .md5 and .sha1. How can I stop/ask maven not to generate them.
By default I am using maven goal :  clean package install

Though I don't see any relation but to add more info if some how its related Or clue somewhere :- I am using maven plugin from [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) and trying to host the jar on hosted [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/products-sonatype)
For some reason my jars have namin convention of having *SNAPSHOT* there.

Comment: Using `mvn clean package install` is an hint that you didn't understand the [Maven lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecyce_Reference). It is absolutely sufficient to use `mvn install` or `mvn clean package` furthermore the generated checksums are part of maven and can't be suppressed apart from that it does not make sense...